# C++ - How can I avoid this header from appearing twice?

Tags: c++, header, include-guards

At: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/110-a-first-look-at-the-preprocessor/

Under Header guards, there are those code snippets:

add.h:

```
#include "mymath.h"
int add(int x, int y);
```

subtract.h:

```
#include "mymath.h"
int subtract(int x, int y);
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "add.h"
#include "subtract.h"
```

How can I avoid `#include "mymath.h"` from appearing twice in `main.cpp`?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it being included twice?

Comment: The point of include guards isn't to stop the preprocessor from seeing the same `#include` more than once, it's to stop the actual code in mymath.h from being included twice.  Assuming you have include guards in mymath.h, you're fine.

Comment: The answer is actually in the next paragraph in that tutorial. Why are you asking that question here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lines right below that example explain it.  Your `mymath.h` file should look like this:

```
#ifndef MYMATH_H
#define MYMATH_H

// your declarations here

#endif
```

Every header file should follow this basic format.  This allows a header file to be included by any file that needs it (both header and source files), but the actual declarations will only be included *at most once* in each source file.

Answer (score 4):

use #pragma once if you using MS VC++ or the standard way

inside mymath.h

```
#ifndef MYMATH_H
#define MYMATH_H

[code here]

#endif // MYMATH_H
```

Answer (score 2):

That's ok if they included twice if **all** the headers files have *header guards*.  The second and all subsequent inclusions would just add empty lines and there won't be any code duplication.  Just make sure that `mymath.h` has header guards as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your header guards in any header, also in mymath.h.